# How do I replace xen kernel on RHEL5 with non-xen kernel?

Tags: linux

I have a RHEL5 machine that wont boot in VMware because it's running a xen kernel and VMware doesn't support this. I need to install a non-xen kernel and boot to that instead. I've actually done this about 6 months ago but can't remember how I did it. I know I should have made notes, so I know it's possible. I can only boot into the OS using Linux rescue (but I do have network/Internet access). When I try to run commands like yum I get all kinds of errors maybe because I'm in the rescue mode? Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in rescue mode, odds are that it's on an install-DVD and in that case the DVD is already mounted in the drive.

Refer to Red Hat's advice in *[Booting into Rescue Mode](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s1-rescuemode-boot.html)*:

- make a `chroot` so you can work on the "real" system
- mount the DVD (in the `chroot`)
- change working directories to the `Packages` directory on the DVD
- review the `kernel-2.*.rpm` packages (probably only one to choose from: I recall **`2.6.18`**)
- use `yum` to install the selected *package file*, e.g.,

  `yum install kernel-2.6.18*.x86_64.rpm`
- exit from the rescue environment
- reboot

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Makes perfect sense. Only one issue I need to overcome. I can't mount the cdrom whilst in rescue mode. It keeps telling me the device doesn't exist and I don't see it in /dev. Tried attaching the OS image via vmware attach to data store image, no go. I am currently burning the RHEL5 image to a DVD. I am going to place this DVD in the VM host and tell the guest to attach to that and then see if it shows up in /dev. If not, I'm stumped. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. It was device hda.

Comment: All set. Now boots with non Xen kernel. Thanks again for the guidance Thomas !!!